# HBase: load master coprocessor from HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, nosql, hbase, hdfs

Is it possible to load HBase master coprocessor from HDFS based on HBase configuration files? I'd like to avoid things like direct coprocessor class placement on HBase master local FS.
If yes, could you please explain how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally came to user jar included into HBase CLASSPATH and distributed over all cluster nodes. Something like 'hbase-extension.jar'. This allowed lot of things related to HBase to be modified / improved. Especially to Lily HBase indexer.

But by now HBase cannot use HDFS located jars for MASTER co-processors. Hope this may change soon.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Load from Shell` section [here](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/coprocessor_introduction). The good thing is that there is no need to restart the HBase to register the Coprocessors.

Comment: Praveen, I understand you're trying to help but... was there ANY word about MASTER in this chapter? I widely use this approach (OK, usually from API) but it is applicable only on a per table basis.